# custom node module's dependency not installed on root

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules

I have a app project and 2 node module projects.

The dependencies structure is something like this:

```
App {
  NodeModule1 {
    NodeModule2,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

The problem I have is that my NodeModule2 instead of being installed on the root of app's node_module `App/node_modules/NodeModule2`, it is installed in `App/node_modules/NodeModule1/node_modules/NodeModule2`

This is causing some error on runtime, says my NodeModule2 is not found. My workaround is to add NodeModule2 into App directly, which is not an idea solution.

All other dependencies of NodeModule1 are installed at App/node_modules/.. as expected.

My NodeModule2's package.json

```
{
  "name": "NodeModule2",
  "version": "0.0.2-20210202.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I HAVE GOT IT

In order for sub node_module to be appeared on the root level, all its `peerDependencies`s' versions must be matched with App's.

In my case both of my App and NodeModule1 has `dependency` of `react-native-picker-select` but with different versions.

```
App {
  dependency: {
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.0"
  }
}

NodeModule1 {
  dependency: {
    "react-native-picker-select": "8.0.0"
  }
}

NodeModule2 {
  peerDependency: {
    "react-native-picker-select": "8.0.0"
  }
}
```

In this case, App received 8.0.4 and NodeModule1 received 8.0.0.
Yarn puts `NodeModule2` under `NodeModule1` and to shared the same dependency version 8.0.0.

Fix: Make sure all versions are matched in App, NodeModule1, and NodeModule2.